# Is this "robots.txt" file really preventing all crawling of our website? I'm trying to find out why our SEO is so poor

Tags: seo, robots.txt

So I've been assigned to take a look at our SEO (an area I have some, but not amazing competence in), and the first thing I noticed is that our robots.txt file says the following:

```
# go away
User-agent: *
Disallow: /
```

Now, I'm pretty competent at reading computer, and as far as I can tell, this says ALL spiders shouldn't look at ANYTHING in the root directory or below.

Am I reading this correctly? Because that just seems insane.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Maybe someone didn't want to pay for spider traffic?

Regardless, you are reading it correctly:

http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html

> Web site owners use the /robots.txt file to give instructions about
>   their site to web robots; this is called The Robots Exclusion
>   Protocol.   It works likes this: a robot wants to vists a Web site
>   URL, say http://www.example.com/welcome.html. Before it does so, it
>   firsts checks for http://www.example.com/robots.txt, and finds:

```
 User-agent: *
 Disallow: /
```

> *The `"User-agent: *"` means this section applies to all robots. The
>   `"Disallow: /"` tells the robot that it should not visit any pages on
>   the site.*

Answer (score 1):

I've put this sort of robots.txt in place when first developing a site because I don't want it to be indexed by Google and others before it's ready.

I've also forgotten to edit that after the site has gone live. *[facepalm](https://www.google.com/search?q=facepalm)*

Comment: The problem with this is that this is a site for a multi-million dollar web design company, with over 35 employees, which has been around for over 15 years!

Comment: Umm, choke, ROFL